# Why can't my Ubuntu laptop ping other computers in the same LAN?

Tags: wireless, networking

The scenario:

- `192.168.1.1` -- the router
- `192.168.1.2` -- a server, connected to the router via ethernet
- `192.168.1.3` -- laptop A, connected to the router via WiFi
- `192.168.1.8` -- laptop B, connected to the router via WiFi

All computers (except the router) run Ubuntu. All computers can access the Internet.

The problem:

- the server can reach both the router and laptop A, but not laptop B
- laptop A can reach both the router and the server, but not laptop B
- laptop B can reach only the router, not the server nor laptop A

With "reach" here I mean: `ping`, `arping`, `ssh` or any other protocol over TCP/IPv4. IPv6 is not supported by the router.

What's going on? How do I resolve the problem?

## Additional information

- When trying `ping` from or to laptop B, I get `Destination Host Unreachable`.
- When trying to connect (e.g. via ssh) from or to laptop B, I get `No route to host`.
- On laptop A, I've tried manually adding the MAC address of laptop B to the ARP cache with:

  ```
  $ arp -s 192.168.1.8 68:a3:c4:10:53:da
  ```

  But with no luck.
- `tracepath` does not return anything useful:

  ```
  $ tracepath -n 192.168.1.8  # Run on laptop A
   1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
   1:  192.168.1.3                                         2996.146ms !H
       Resume: pmtu 1500 

  $ tracepath -n 192.168.1.3  # Run on laptop B
   1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
   1:  192.168.1.8                                         2997.463ms !H
       Resume: pmtu 1500
  ```
- The router's DHCP server returns the correct addresses, on any computer (all computers use Avahi).
- The router supports 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz, but both laptops are using the 2.4 GHz band, according to `nm-tool` (at the moment, laptop A is on 2462 MHz and laptop B is on 2464 MHz).
- `iptables` chains are empty, and all of them have policy `ACCEPT`.
- `route` and `ip route` return the expected output, on all computers:

  ```
  $ ip route  # From laptop A
  default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
  192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.3  metric 9 

  $ ip route  # From laptop B
  default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  proto static 
  192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.8  metric 9
  ```
- `nmap -sP 192.168.1.1/24` returns:

  - when run from laptop A or from the server: all the addresses in the LAN, except `192.168.1.8`
  - when run from laptop B: only `192.168.1.1` and `192.168.1.8`.
- This is `lspci` from laptop B:

  ```
  12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
          Subsystem: Dell Inspiron M5010 / XPS 8300
          Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
          Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
          Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
          Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
          Region 0: Memory at fbb00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
          Capabilities: <access denied>
          Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
  ```

  Yes, it's the nasty Broadcom, I know. But I'm using the free driver (`brcmsmac`).
- Relevant `dmesg`:

  ```
  [   19.597541] brcmsmac bcma0:0: mfg 4bf core 812 rev 24 class 0 irq 17
  [   19.610379] ieee80211 phy0: registered radio enabled led device: brcmsmac-phy0:radio gpio: 243
  [   23.021922] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
  [   23.022072] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_config: change power-save mode: false (implement)
  [   24.920808] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
  [   24.920828] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
  [   24.977079] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: disassociated
  [   24.977091] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: false (implement)
  [   24.985762] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcmsmac: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: associated
  [   24.985769] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: qos enabled: true (implement)
  [   25.135123] brcmsmac bcma0:0: brcms_ops_bss_info_changed: arp filtering: 1 addresses (implement)
  ```

Comment: maybe your router is forcing some sort of isolation between different machines connected over wifi?

Comment: @epeleg: not really... other than the two laptops I also have a tablet, a wifi printer, some smartphones, and they all work fine. Except laptop B.

Comment: could you please run from **laptopB** sudo iptables --list and post the input here, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that info. Updated question, but nothing useful found.

Comment: what about "ip route" what is the output?

Comment: Updated question

Comment: what about the iptables results of the server?

Comment: Have you tried releasing the IP address on laptop B and requesting a new one from the server? There may be some sort of conflict lingering somewhere. Or try to set a static IP address on laptop B?

Comment: please add the output from netstat -rn for each of the laptops and the server

Comment: @Jos: I tried many restarts, many IP address combinations (both static and DHCP). I even tried explicitly disabling IPv6. @LearnTitan: same as laptop A. @sweetfa: same as `route -n`.

Comment: Can you please provide an `lspci` of laptop B and drop a comment to @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby: there you are.

Comment: As I suspected...  I'm going to fetch an expert on this (not flagging as a duplicate for now... )

Comment: Fascinating. I am researching and I wonder if this is related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bcmwl/+bug/414724 Note it is the same chipset but the wrong, IMO, driver. May I assume none of the other computers on the network use the Broadcom 4313 chipset and brcmsmac?

Comment: Is there any clue here on laptop B? dmesg | grep -e brcm -e arp Thanks.

Comment: @chili555: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cFods1KSWsQ  ;-)

Comment: @chili555: there you go. By the way, I do not believe that bug is relevant. As I said, even manually editing the ARP cache didn't help.

Comment: @heyhey Editing the arp cache on all the other computers?

Comment: @chili555: not *all* of them. I just played with the two laptops.

Comment: @heyhey Aside from trying a more recent driver _brcmsmac_, I have no other suggestions. Shall I offer that as an answer?

Comment: @chili555: I'll be honest with you. I do know a way to work around this problem: restarting the router makes things work again for a few days. So it's not a real pity if this issue can't be resolved. Feel free to post your answer :)

Comment: I'll post my proposal. If it were me, I might get a timer and turn the router off at 3:30am every night.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the driver *brcmsmac* backported from kernel version 3.18.

Download this to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.18.1/backports-3.18.1-1.tar.xz Right click and select Extract here. Then:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential

cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.18-1
make defconfig-brcmsmac
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if it works as expected. We will probably have one additional step.